# How to make a list with just the used inputs for a C module

Tags: c

I have a large module that uses a very large input buffer, consisting of many structures which, in turn, contain other structures and in the end each structure has several variables.

Out of these hundreds of input variables, my module (standalone C entity) uses only a fraction.

I would like to know if there is a way to make a list that will contain only the variables used in my module (would be perfect if it contains the variable type and links to structure/s that contains it).

I tried Doxygen (1.8.5) but I could generate a doc with all input variables, only.

**[Later EDIT]**
I add an example code and the desired outcome:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct subS1{
    unsigned char bIn1;
    unsigned char bIn2;
} subS1;

typedef struct S1{
    struct subS1 stMySubStruct1;
    struct subS1 stMySubStruct2;
    struct subS1 stMySubStruct3;
} MyInputStruct_t;

void Foo1(MyInputStruct_t *Input);
void Foo2(MyInputStruct_t *Input);

MyInputStruct_t stMyInputStruct = {{1, 2}, {0, 0}, {9, 6}}; // large input buffer

int main() {
    Foo1(&stMyInputStruct); // call to my Module 'main' function
    return 0;
}

void Foo1(MyInputStruct_t *Input)
{
    if(Input->stMySubStruct1.bIn1 == 1)
    {
        printf("bIn1 = %d\n", Input->stMySubStruct1.bIn1); // stMySubStruct1.bIn1 is used (read or write)
    }
    Foo2(Input);
    return;
}

void Foo2(MyInputStruct_t *Input)
{
    if(Input->stMySubStruct3.bIn2 == 0)
    {
        printf("bIn2 = %d\n", Input->stMySubStruct3.bIn2); // stMySubStruct3.bIn2 is used (read or write)
    }
    return;
}
```

The list with just the used inputs for Foo1(): e.g

- stMyInputStruct.stMySubStruct1.bIn1 -> is used in Foo1()
- stMyInputStruct.stMySubStruct1.bIn2 -> is NOT used
- ...
- stMyInputStruct.stMySubStruct3.bIn2 -> is used in Foo2()

Comment: I saw a similar solution, but incomplete, in Doxygen: to use the Referenced by Relation. But instead of "for each documented function all documented functions referencing it will be listed." I would like to have "for each documented input variable all documented functions referencing it will be listed."!

Comment: Doxygen version 1.8.5 is very old (August 23, 2013), the current version is 1.9.5 so you should definitely update your version. Probably your best bet are `REFERENCED_BY_RELATION` and `REFERENCES_RELATION`. When this doesn't give what you want add a small example to your question and indicate what is missing.

Comment: You could run the module's code through a parser like [pycparser](https://github.com/eliben/pycparser) and walk the AST, filtering for everything referencing the root/main data-structure. If you could post the main data-structure, maybe I could post an answer with sample-code..

Comment: Thank you for your answers, but no luck so far. Latest Doxygen with the mentioned parameters didn't create what I was expecting. pycparser created a very hard to read list of all defined variables, but nothing related to their usage.  I guess only a C compiler is able to supply such info.

Comment: @SandulescuBogdan in the general case, you need something with semantic understanding of C-code. Something like a compiler or a parser (I suggest pycparser) can do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a five-minute hack to demonstrate what I mean, so take it with a grain of salt and for what it is.

So first I downloaded pycparser from https://github.com/eliben/pycparser/

Then I edit the C-generator from https://github.com/eliben/pycparser/blob/master/pycparser/c_generator.py

... adding two lines to the constructor-code (adding two vars `struct_refs` + `struct_ref`):

```py
class CGenerator(object):
    """ Uses the same visitor pattern as c_ast.NodeVisitor, but modified to
        return a value from each visit method, using string accumulation in
        generic_visit.
    """
    def __init__(self, reduce_parentheses=False):
        """ Constructs C-code generator
            reduce_parentheses:
                if True, eliminates needless parentheses on binary operators
        """
        # Statements start with indentation of self.indent_level spaces, using
        # the _make_indent method.
        self.indent_level = 0
        self.reduce_parentheses = reduce_parentheses

        # newly added variables here
        self.struct_refs = set()
        self.struct_ref = None
```

Then I edit two visitor-functions, to make them save information about the struct-references they parse:

```py
    def visit_ID(self, n):
        if self.struct_ref:
            self.struct_refs.add(self.struct_ref + "->" + n.name)
        return n.name

    def visit_StructRef(self, n):
        sref = self._parenthesize_unless_simple(n.name)
        self.struct_ref = sref
        self.struct_refs.add(sref)
        res = sref + n.type + self.visit(n.field)
        self.struct_ref = None
        return res
```

Running this modified piece of Python script over your example code, collects this information:

```bash
>>> cgen.struct_refs
{'Input',
 'Input->stMySubStruct1',
 'Input->stMySubStruct1->bIn1',
 'Input->stMySubStruct3',
 'Input->stMySubStruct3->bIn2'}
```

So with a bit more work, it should be able to do the job more generally.

This of course breaks apart in the face of `memcpy`, struct-member-access-through-pointers etc.

You can also try exploiting structure in your code as well. E.g. If you always call your input-struct "Input", things gets easier.

Comment: Thank you @Morten Jensen. I tried calling the `print(generator.visit_StructRef(ast))`, from c-to-c.py (as this one was reading a file .C and was calling the c_generator.py) but I got errors:
`AttributeError: 'FileAST' object has no attribute 'name'`

Comment: As I said, this was a 5-minute hack :) You will probably have to read the documentation and add error-handling etc., to make it robust enough for the real deal. Try just wrapping the code I added in `try/except` and ignore errors, maybe that works well enough?

Comment: @SandulescuBogdan now that I re-read your comment: you are close. Call `generator.visit(ast)` instead! You need to pass the top-level AST to the "top-level"-visitor